# Print match and line after match

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics, fasta, text-manipulation

I have this file containing 82 pairs of IDs:

```
EmuJ_000063620.1    EgrG_000063620.1    253 253
EmuJ_000065200.1    EgrG_000065200.1    128 128
EmuJ_000081200.1    EgrG_000081200.1    1213    1213
EmuJ_000096200.1    EgrG_000096200.1    295 298
EmuJ_000114700.1    EgrG_000114700.1    153 153
EmuJ_000133800.1    EgrG_000133800.1    153 153
EmuJ_000139900.1    EgrG_000144400.1    2937    2937
EmuJ_000164600.1    EgrG_000164600.1    167 167
```

and I have two other files with the sequences for `EmuJ_*` IDs and `EgrG_*` IDs as follows:

`EgrG_sequences.fasta`:

```
>EgrG_000632500.1
MKKKSHRKSPEGNHSLTKAANKDTAKCNEERGRNIGQSNEEENATRSEKDREGDEDRNLREYVISIAQKYYPHLVSCMRQDDDNQASADARGADGANDEEHCPKHCPRLNAQKYYLYSATCNHHCEDSQASCDEEGDGKRLLKQCLLWLTERYYPSLAARIRQCNDDQASSNAHGADETDDGDRRLKQALLLFAKKLYPCVTTCIRHCVADHTSHDARGVDEEVDGEQLLKQCLHSSAQKFYPRLAACVCHCDADHASTETCGALGVGNAERCPQQCPCLCAQQYYVQSATCVHHCDNEQSSPETRGVKEDVDVEQLLKQCLLMFAEKFHPTLAAGIRSCADDESSHVASVEGEDDADKQRLKQYLLLFAQKYYPHLIAYIQKRDDDQSSSSVRDSGEEANEEEERLKQCLLLFAQKLYPRLVAYTGRCDSNQSTSDGCSVDGEEAEKHYLKQSLLLLAQKYYPSLAAYLRQFDDNQSSSDVRSVDEEEAEKRHLKQGLLFFAEKYYPSLATYIRRCDDDQSSSDARVVDEVDDEDRRLKQGLLLLAQKYYPPLANYIRHSQSSFNVCGADEKEDEEHCLNQLPRLCAQEAYIRSSSCSHHCDDDQASNDTLVVDKEEEEKYRLKQGLLLLAQKFYPPLATCIHQCDDQSSHDTRGVDEEEAEEQLLKKCLLMFAEKFYPSLAATIHHSVYDQASFDMRDVDTENDETHCLSLSAENYSTASTTCIHHSDGDQSTSDACGVEEGDVEEQRLKRGLLLLAQKYYPSLAAYICQCDDYQPSSDVCGVGEEDTGEERLKQCLLLFAKKFYPSLASRNSQCGDNLILNDEVVGETVINSDTDTDEVTPVEKSTAVCDEVDEVPFKYVGSPTPLSDVDVDSLEKVIPPNDLTAHSSFQNSLDHSVEGGYPDRAFYIGRHTVESADSTAPLSKSSSTKLYFSNTDEFPTEEEVSSPIAPLSIQRRIRIYLEDLENVRKVSLIPLCKTDKFGNPQEEIIIDSNLDDDTDESKLSSVDVEFTMEQADATPLDLEAQDEDLKNCVAIILKHIWSELMECIRREGLSDVYELSLGDRRIEVPQDDVCLVR*
>EgrG_000006700.1
MTDTKGPDESYFEKEAFSSLPQPVDSPSASATDTDRIPVVAVSLPVSSGSIDVNCNCSCYLIICETKLIIDYQMTRKW*
```

and so on. The same for `EmuJ_sequences.fasta`
I need to get the sequences for each pair and write one after the other maintaining the order like this:

```
>EmuJ_000063620.1
AEPGSGDFDANALRDLANEHQRRVQQKQADLETYELQVLDSVLELTSQLSLNLNEKISKAYENQCRLDTEVKRLCSNIQTFNRQVDMWNKEILDINSALKELGDAETWSQKLCRDVQIIHDTLQAADK*
>EgrG_000063620.1
AEPGSGDFDANALRDLANEHQRRVQQKQADLETYELQVLDSVLELTSQLSLNLNEKISKAYDNQCRLDTEVKRLCSNIQTFNCQVDLWNKEILDINSALKELGDAETWSQKLCRDVQIIHDTLQAADK*
>EmuJ_000065200.1
MLCLITPFPSVVPVCVRTCVCMCPCPLLLILYTWSAYLVPFSLPLCLYAHFHIRFLPPFSSLSIPRFLTHSLFLPSYPPLTMLRMKKSLAPCPAERR*
>EgrG_000065200.1
MLCLVTSFPSAVPVCMRTCVCMCSCPLLLILYTWSAYLVPFSLPLCLYTHLHIRFLPPFPSLAIPRFLTHPLFLPTSLYVADKKEPSAMPRRASLRQMLLIVLLQELH*
>EmuJ_000081200.1
MNSLRIFAVVITCLMVVGFSYSIHPTFPSYQSVVWHSSANTGYECRDGICGYRCSNPWCHGFGSILHPQMGVQEMWGSAAHGRHAHSRAMTEFLAKASPEDVTMLIESTPNIDEVITSLDGEAVTILINKLPNLRRVMEELKPQTKMHIVSKLCGKVGSAMEWTEARRNDGSGMWNEYGSGWEGIDAIQDLEAEVIMRCVQDCGYCAHPTMDGGYVFDPIPIKDVAVYDDSMNWQPQLPTPATSVSSMDPLVLRSIILNMPNLNDILMQVDPVYLQSALVHVPGFGAYASSMDAYTLHSMIVGLPYVRDIVASMDARLLQRMIAHIPNIDAILFGGNAVISQPTMPDMPRKAPRAEEPDAKTTEVAGGMSDEANIMDRKFMEYIISTMPNVPTRFANVLLHVKPDYVRYIIEKHGNLHGLLAKMNAQTLQYVIAHVPKFGVILSNMNRNTLKVVFDKLPNIAKFLADMNPRVVRAIVAKLPSLAKYTPTDPTTTALPTSVTLVPELGTEFSSYAATASATEEPTVTVDYANLLRSKIPLIDNVIKMSDPEKVAILRDNLLDVSRILVNLDPTMLRNINSIIFNATKMLNELSVFLVEYPLEYLHKEGKSGVAVNKSEQVGTTGENGVSSIAVEKLQMVLLKIPLFDQFLKWIDQKKLHELLNKIPTLLEVIATANQETLDKINSLLHDAIATMNTAKKLIVTGICRKLAEEGKLRLPRVCPSAST*
>EgrG_000081200.1
MNLLRIFAVVITCLIVVGFGYPTHPTFPSYQTAVWHSSANTGYRCRAGICGYRCSSPWCHGFESALYPQMAMQEMWGSGAHGRHAHSRTMTEFLMKASPEDLTMLIESTPNIDEVITSLDSEAIIILINKLPNLRRVMEKLKPQTKMHIVSKLCDKVGNAMEWAGARRNDGSGMWNEYGSVWEGIDAIQDLEAEMITRCVQDCGYCAHPTMDGGYVFDPIPIKDVAVYDDSMNWQPQLPMPATLVSNMDPHVLRSIILNMPNLDDILMQVDPVHLQSALMYVPGFGTYASSMDAYTLHSMIVGLPYVRDIVASMDARLLQWMIAHIPNIDAILFGGNAVISQPTMPDMPRKAPKAEEPDAKTTEVAGGMSDEANIMDRKFMEYIISTMPNVPARFANVLLHVKPDYVRYIIENHGNLHGLLAKMNAQTLQYVIAHVPKFGVILSNMNRNTLKVVFDKLPNIAKFLADMNPNVVRAIVAKLPSLAKYTPTDPTTTALPTSVTLVPELGTEFSSYAPTASVTEASMVTVDYAHLLRSKIPLIDNVIKMSDPAKVAILRDNLLDVGTTDENGVSSITVEKLQMVLLKIPLFDQFLNWIDSKKLHALLQKIPTLLEVIATANQEALDKINLLLHDAIATMNTAKKLIVTSICRKLAEEGKLRLPRVCPSTST*
```

And so on.

I wrote a script in bash to do this and it worked like I wanted, it was very simple. Now I'm trying to do the same in Python (which I'm learning), but I'm having a hard time to do the same in a pythonic way.
I've tried this, but I've got only the first pair and then it stopped:

```
rbh=open('rbh_res_eg-not-sec.txt', 'r')
ems=open('em_seq.fasta', 'r')
egs=open('eg_seq.fasta', 'r')

for l in rbh:
    emid=l.split('\t')[0]
    egid=l.split('\t')[1]
    # ids=emid+'\n'+egid 
    # print ids # just to check if split worked
    for lm in ems:      
        if emid in lm:
            print lm.strip()
            print next(ems).strip()
    for lg in egs:
        if egid in lg:
            print lg.strip()
            print next(egs).strip()
```

I've tried some variations but I've got only the IDs, without the sequences.
So, how can I find the ID in the sequence file, print it and the line after it (the line with sequence referring to the ID)?
Please, let me know if I explained it clearly.

Comment: why posting a snapshot of your output (with some info removed) instead of copying/pasting the result as _text_ ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ok, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a file moves the file pointer until it reaches the end of the file (the last line), so after the first iteration of your outer loop, the `ems` and `egs` files are exhausted.

The quick&dirty workaround would be to reset the `ems` and `egs` pointers to zero at the end of the outer loop, ie:

```
for line in rbh:
    # no need to split twice
    parts = line.split("\t") 
    emid, egid = parts[0].strip(), parts[1].strip()

    for lm in ems:      
        if emid in lm:
            print lm.strip()
            print next(ems).strip()
    ems.seek(0) # reset the file pointer

    for lg in egs:
        if egid in lg:
            print lg.strip()
            print next(egs).strip()
    egs.seek(0) # reset the file pointer
```

Note that calling `next(iterator)` while already iterating over `iterator` will consume one more item of the iterator, as illustrated here:

```
>>> it = iter(range(20))
>>> for x in it:
...     print x, next(it)
... 
0 1
2 3
4 5
6 7
8 9
10 11
12 13
14 15
16 17
18 19
```

As you can see, we don't iter on each element of our range here... Given your file format it should not be a huge problem but I thought I'd still warn you about it.

Now your algorithm is far from efficient - for each line of the `rbh` file it will read scan the whole `ems` and `egs` files again and again.

_NB : the following assumes that each emid / egid will appear *at most* once in the fasta files._

If your `ems` and `egs` files are not too large and you have enough available memory, you could load them into a pair of dicts and do a mere dict lookup (which is O(1) and possibly one of the most optimized operation in Python)

```
# warning: totally untested code

def fastamap(path):
    d = dict()
    with open(path) as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            line = line.strip()
            # skip empty lines.
            if not line:
                continue

            # sanity check: we should only see 
            # lines starting with ">", the "value"
            # lines being consumed by the `next(f)` call
            if not line.startswith(">"):
                raise ValueError(
                    "in file %s: line %s doesn't start with '>'" % (
                      path, num
                    ))

            # ok, proceed
            d[line.lstrip(">")] = next(f).strip()

    return d

ems = fastamap('em_seq.fasta') 
egs = fastamap('eg_seq.fasta')
with open('rbh_res_eg-not-sec.txt') as rhb:
    for line in rhb:
        parts = line.split("\t") 
        emid, egid = parts[0].strip(), parts[1].strip()

        if emid in ems:
            print emid
            print ems[emid]

        if egid in egs:
            print egid
            print egs[egid]
```

If this doesn't fly because of memory issues, well bad luck you're stuck with sequential scan (unless you want to use some database system but this might be a bit overkill), but - always assuming the emid/egid each only appears once in the fasta files - you can at least exit the inner loops once you've find your target:

```
for l in rbh:
    # no need to split twice, you can just unpack
    emid, egid = l.split('\t')

    for lm in ems:      
        if emid in lm:
            print lm.strip()
            print next(ems).strip()
            break # no need to go further

    ems.seek(0) # reset the file pointer

    # etc...
```

Comment: the .seek(0) approach worked. Thank you. And just to answer some things you said: yes the ID's appear once in the fasta files. I thought about creating a dcitionary but each fasta file have more than 10k sequences. I don't know if it would be good to create a dictionary, or would it be?

Comment: One more thing, if I do
`emid, egid = l.split('\t')`
I get:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ortho-pair_get_seq.py", line 9, in <module>
    emid, egid=l.split('\t')
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

But if I do like I originally did:
`emid=l.split('\t')[0]
egid=l.split('\t')[1]`

it works.

Comment: Wrt/ the issue with split I overlooked your source file having more than two items per line, I'll edit my post to fix this.

Comment: Wrt your files sizes 10k lines is big indeed but not huge considering today's standards with computers having gigabytes of ram. Whether you want this optimization depends on your needs (is it fast enough without it?) and memory constraints (does the computer this will run on have enough spare memory)

Comment: FWIW, 10k entries with 20 chars per key and 200 chars per value eats something like 10Mb on my computer (python 2.7.6). Which leaves me with quite a few Gb to spares xD